How to get e-office notification from USPTO
It's quite strange that I applied a utility patent but I can't be added to their email notification list.
I try to find the instruction but unsuccessfully, they just merge all into [patentcenter][1]
[1]: https://patentcenter.uspto.gov/ it seems we/applicant should register somewhere to get the office action by email,
anyone has a official link on how to do it, or could enlighten me, it seems customer number and confirmation no needed but I don't have a portal of this page at all.

Do you have a customer number ? Have you called the helpful people at the inventors assistance center IAC 800-786-9199
